# Java - From two equal objects, return new object coalescing all fields

Tags: java, spring, algorithm, oop, data-structures

sorry, but I couldn't find a solution to this:

I got this coalesce method which has been working fine for two single values, but I would like to extend it to iterate through any object and return a new object after applying the coalesce in all fields. I wanted to do it with generics, so it work with any given object type.

This is the coalesce method:

```
public static <T> T coalesce(T one, T two) {
    return one != null ? one : two;
}
```

The idea is to improve to method like this:

```
public static <T,Z> T coalesceAll(T one, T two) {
    
    T finalObject;
    
    for (Z field : getFields(one.getClass())) {
        finalObject.field = coalesce(one.field, two.field);
    }
    
    return finalObject;
}
```

Any idea on how to implement this in Java? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are many ways of doing this. What's the exact purpose of this method? I mean, where and when are you going to use it?

Comment: @fluffy I'm using this for PUT requests in my API

Comment: It sounds more of a PATCH rather than PUT. It might be much easier to implement it on the representation layer: merging two objects into one like this is pretty easy doable by any major library (assuming your messages are JSON or XML), and this can be done fully automatically. Smutje's solution is really nice but it requires boilerplating and your objects to implement a specific interface (but not implementation). D.Kastier's solution is based on reflection, but usually Java beans conventions (default constructor + setters/getters only) is more preferable (especially in the Spring world).

Comment: I implemented a similar thing recently and I implemented it using dynamic proxies to detect changed properties so that I had some magic behind the scenes, but zero boilerplate. You choose anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this by delegating the coalescing to the actual classes. Making this generic via reflection might be possible but way more complicated:

## Coalesce.java

```
public interface Coalesce<T> {

    T coalesce(T other);

    default <V> V coalesce(V one, V two) {
        return one != null ? one : two;
    }
}
```

## Person.java

```
public class Person implements Coalesce<Person> {

    private final Integer id;

    private final String name;

    public Person(Integer id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public Person coalesce(Person other) {
        final int id = coalesce(this.id, other.id);
        final String name = coalesce(this.name, other.name);

        return new Person(id, name);
    }
}
```

## Book.java

```
public class Book implements Coalesce<Book> {

    private final String title;

    private final String author;

    public Book(String title, String author) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    @Override
    public Book coalesce(Book other) {
        final String title = coalesce(this.title, other.title);
        final String author = coalesce(this.author, other.author);

        return new Book(title, author);
    }
}
```

## Main.java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Person personA = new Person(1, null);
        final Person personB = new Person(2, "Bob");
        final Person coalescedPerson = personA.coalesce(personB);
        System.out.println(coalescedPerson.getId()); // 1
        System.out.println(coalescedPerson.getName()); // Bob
        
        final Book bookA = new Book(null, "J. R. R. Tolkien");
        final Book bookB = new Book("The Hobbit", null);
        final Book coalescedBook = bookA.coalesce(bookB);
        System.out.println(coalescedBook.getTitle()); // The Hobbit
        System.out.println(coalescedBook.getAuthor()); // J. R. R. Tolkien
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Smutje! I implemented your solution in my case and it helped to decrease some boilerplate code!

Answer (score 1):

I like more the answer by [Smutje](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65127776/5734097). But I also like reflection (a lot!).

**EDIT:** As @fluffy pointed out, in the comments, my **old code failed** for `inherited fields`; also I observed that it will not work with `primitive` value (like `int` or `double`).

So I decided to recreate it!, **now works** with `primitive` and `class inheritance`.

---

The `coalesce` code

```
private static void doCoalesce(Field field, Object src, Object target) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    // remove "protection" (for private & final fields)
    boolean isAccessible = field.isAccessible();
    field.setAccessible(true);

    // Copy value if null or default primitive value (0 - zero)
    if (isNull(field.getType(), field.get(target))) {
        field.set(target, field.get(src));
    }

    // restore "protection"
    field.setAccessible(isAccessible);
}

private static void doCoalesceByClass(Object src, Object target, Class cls) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    for (Field field : cls.getDeclaredFields()) {
        doCoalesce(field, src, target);
    }
}

private static void doCoalesce(Object src, Object target) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    Class cls = target.getClass();

    while (cls != Object.class) {
        doCoalesceByClass(src, target, cls);
        cls = cls.getSuperclass();
    }
}

public static Object coalesce(Object... objects) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    switch (objects.length) {
        case 0: return null;
        case 1: return objects[0];
        default: throwExceptionIfDifferentClass(objects); break;
    }

    Object finalObject = instantiateDefaultClass(objects[0].getClass());
    for (Object object : objects) {
        doCoalesce(object, finalObject);
    }

    return finalObject;
}
```

---

The `auxiliary` code

```
private static Object instantiateDefaultClass(Class cls) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    final Constructor constructor = cls.getConstructors()[0];
    final List<Object> params = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Class<?> pType : constructor.getParameterTypes()) {
        params.add((pType.isPrimitive()) ? 0 : null);
    }
    return constructor.newInstance(params.toArray());
}

private static void throwExceptionIfDifferentClass(Object... objects) {
    Class cls = objects[0].getClass();

    for (Object obj : objects) {
        if (obj.getClass() != cls) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Objects MUST be of the same class");
        }
    }
}

private static boolean isNull(Class cls, Object value) {
    if (!cls.isPrimitive()) {
        return value == null;
    }

    // Primitive types
    if (cls == Boolean.TYPE)   return (boolean) value;
    if (cls == Byte.TYPE)      return    (byte) value == 0;
    if (cls == Character.TYPE) return    (char) value == 0;
    if (cls == Short.TYPE)     return   (short) value == 0;
    if (cls == Long.TYPE)      return    (long) value == 0;
    if (cls == Double.TYPE)    return  (double) value == 0;
    if (cls == Float.TYPE)     return   (float) value == 0;
    return false;
}
```

---

The `test` code

```
public static class Book
{
    public final String title;
    public final String author;
    public final long isbn;

    public Book(String title, String author, long isbn) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }
}

public static class AudioBook extends Book
{
    public final String url;

    public AudioBook(String title, String author, long isbn, String url) {
        super(title, author, isbn);
        this.url = url;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    AudioBook b1 = new AudioBook(null, "J. R. R. Tolkien", 9780261103306L, null);
    AudioBook b2 = new AudioBook("The Hobbit", null, 0, "www.thehobbit.com");

    AudioBook finalBook = (AudioBook) coalesce(b1, b2);
    System.out.println(finalBook.author + ", " + finalBook.title + ", " + finalBook.isbn + ", " + finalBook.url);
}
```

Comment: This approach won't work for class hierarchies and it won't work for inherited fields.

Comment: Thank you, @fluffy, for the input. I remodeled everything, now I believe that will work like a charm! (until some other problem turns out)